# Lengthwise center of gravity of a boat based on flotation angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, geometry, estimation, buoyancy

I am trying to determine the center of gravity horizontally along the length of a pontoon boat so I can properly position the load on my lift. Approximate will do. It seems like an impossible question for the manufacturer to answer. If I could take the boat out of the water and weigh each end that would help, but I have no way to lift the boat on an off the trailer on land. It weighs 4000 lbs loaded with fuel, I know that. The fuel and engine are all in the back and weigh 960 lbs. The remaining 3040 lbs should be relatively equally distributed from front to back. The boat is 25'2" long not counting the outboard. It floats at such a nice angle in the water, I feel like it should be easy to approximate from the displacement of the pontoons and some kind of volumetric calculation. I tried imagining them as cones since they are not fully submerged cylinders, but I can't find a good volume calculation for cones that are only partially filled while laying on their sides. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the pontoon is a partially submerged cylinder. If we look at an individual section through the pontoon, we find a partially filled circle:

[image]

The area of the submerged part (the blue piece) can be calculated as the area of the circle, minus the white "slice of pie", and minus the pink triangle:

$$A = \frac{2\theta}{2\pi}\pi r^2 - r\sin\theta \cdot r\cos\theta\\
= \frac12 r^2\left( 2\theta - \sin 2\theta\right)$$

And we can find $\theta$ from

$$d = r(1-\cos\theta)\\
\theta = \cos^{-1}(1-\frac{d}{r})$$

This means that if you know the depth at a given point, and the radius of the pontoon, you can figure out the underwater volume of the pontoon at that point.

Repeat this calculation at multiple points along the hull; how many points you need depends a bit on how deep into the water they are submerged (the shallower they are, the more a little change in depth will affect the result) and take their weighted mean.

Without a better drawing of what your pontoons look like (or what you mean by your "partially filled cones) it's hard to get closer to a useful answer. So I'm puttting this here hoping you will comment / ask questions...

Comment: This makes sense, as far as getting area, and then translating that into volume over say a few centimeters in length (minimal change in d). If I can provide the slope of the waterline can we calculate a volume/distance relationship that would give me a center of gravity? Would it simply be the place where volume in front of and behind location X are equal?

Comment: I should say the volume of water displaced fore and aft of location X. If the volume is equal is that the center of mass? I will get the radius and some depth and slope angles and try to work that out.